# XCode : How to resolve "Linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, wikitude, linker-flags

To sum up my situation : I'm working with XCode7 Objective-C, and i'm debugging on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1, and I want to implement an example of Wikitude SDK (Augmented reality framework)

Here's my problem,

According to the procedure when i've added all the .frameworks that are needed I should add the "-ObjC" in Build Settings >> Other linker flags. When I do the code won't compile anymore

I've read quite a lot of solutions of people who encountered the same issue. Such as "Enable/Disable Bitcode" or "Check the assemblies" or many other things that didn't worked out for me

I also want to say that i've never worked with XCode before and Objective-C is quite new to me. I'm forced to use Objective-C also because the sample code that I follow to build my solution is also on Objective-C and I'm not able to convert it to swift by myself. I also updated my XCode like 2 weeks ago.

If someone can brief me, or give me some guidelines on what I should check/do to unlock this issue it would super nice, and maybe helpful for the next ones. Thanks in advance.

Here is the complete log for the error i get when i add the -ObjC linker flag [The complete log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWSp.png)

**UPDATE**
I finally got it to work, but i'm not sure how.
The true error was not "Linker command..." but architecture types (error : not found for architecture type x86_64

Here's all the things I did in an approximate order

- Checked : General >> Linked Framework and Libraries : so that nothing is missing
- Checked : Build Phases >> Link Binary with Libraries : so that nothing is missing as well
- Modified : Build Settings >> Architectures >> Architectures : armv7, armv7s
- Checked : Build Settings >> Architectures >> Build Active Architecture Only : Yes (Debug)
- Modified : Build Settings >> Architectures >> Valid Architectures : armv7, armv7s
- Deleted : Window >> Projects >> myProject >> Derived Data : Delete
- Clean project
- Plugged the iPhone
- Try to run on my iPhone : fail
- Disabled : Build Settings >> Build Options >> Enable Bitcode
- Run again on my iPhone : success

Comment: Have you tried  `Product` > `Clean` and `Run`? Can you post some error logs?

Comment: Clean & Run doesn't have any effect, here's the logs :
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WTArchitectView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @0yeoj I've added the screenshot link on the next answer

Comment: Looking at the error log it seems it has something to do with the **Build Settings** > **Architectures** but good thing you got it working... :)